# Using method of maximum likelihood find the estimator for $\mathcal N(m,1),m<0$ and $\mathcal U(\theta, 1), \theta<0$

Tags: probability, self-study, normal-distribution, mathematical-statistics, maximum-likelihood

> Using method of maximum likelihood find the estimator for $\mathcal N(m,1)$-normal distribution and $\mathcal U(\theta, 1), \theta<0$

From what I understand, if the parameter is negative it is done a little differently than, if it were positive... I don't see how or why, because normally the estimator is $$m=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}X_k$$ for $\mathcal N(m,1).$

For  $\mathcal U(\theta, 1), \theta<0$ I was thinking that
$$L\left(\theta|{\bf x}\right)=\frac{1}{(1-\theta)^n}$$ and since $\theta<x_1,...,x_n$ that the estimator should be $$\min\{0,Y_1\}$$ where $$Y_1=\min_{1 \leq k \leq n}\{x_k \}$$ I'm supposed to check also whether this is **centered**($\min\{0,Y_1\}$).(I was also told that this estimator is correct, just not sure about $L\left(\theta|{\bf x}\right).$) Thought this was the best place to ask. :D

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag (you will need to remove one of the existing tags) & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: check! ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: The expression for $L(\theta|x)$ cannot be correct--it's not even defined for $\theta=-1$!

Comment: How ${}$ about now?

Comment: 1. "*From what I understand*" -- can you explain from where this understanding arises? You're asking for comment on something you don't explain at all. $\:$ 2. To my recollection, each of these problems (or at least very similar ones, similar enough to be helpful) are discussed a number of times on site. Some site-searches may help you solve your problems.

Comment: It may help to draw the likelihood function in your first problem for a few samples (try drawing it for a sample where the mean is negative and for a sample where the mean is positive).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing the likelihood function:

$$
L(\theta|X) = \begin{cases}
\frac{1}{(1-\theta)^n} & \theta <0; \theta\leq X_{(1)} \leq X_{(2)} \leq  \dots X_{(n)} \leq 1\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

which is a decreasing function of $\theta$ and hence the MLE(given the constraint that $\theta < 0$) is given by: $\min(0, X_{(1)})$ where $X_{(i)}$ represents $i^{th}$ order statistic.

Comment: I have a slight confusion: If the parameter space is $\theta<0$, how can the MLE ever be $0$ (when $X_{(1)}>0$) ? If however the parameter space was $\theta\le 0$, then I can see that the MLE can be $0$.